# __del__ is not being called

Tags: python, python-2.7

Actually, I am new to python . I wanted to delete an object of a class . But, for me **del** is not calling , when it should get called. Following is the code :

```
counter = 2
class P:
    def __init__(self):
            self.x = {}
            self.fun()

    def fun( self ):
            self.x = Q( 2 )
            del self.x
class Q:
    def __init__(self, value):
            self.z = value
    def __Del__( self ):
            global counter
            if self.z == 2:
                    counter -= 1
            print counter

s = P()
```

What I think is it should print counter value . But code does not print anything . Why ??

Comment: You want to call `__del__`, not `__Del__`, right?  If that's the case, the case is all wrong.

Comment: Got it .. __del__ not __Del__.Sorry

Comment: Please be aware that `__del__` isn't guaranteed to be called when the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `__del__`, Python is *case sensitive*; you used an uppercase `D` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `__del__`, not `__Del__`, otherwise you create another method, not the one that is invoked when calling `del` on an object.